# Maatwebsite exported(generated) Excel (Laravel Excel) file performance issue while opening

Tags: laravel, phpexcel, maatwebsite-excel

We'are using Maatwebsite version 3.1.0 with Laravel version 6.x.

Excel files that are exported by this composer package are too slow to edit by Excel program than same files generated by copy/paste all datasets from exported excel.

The size of output file exported by Maatwebsite is rather smaller than the file generated by copy/paste but is very slow to edit(or scroll down, and other manipulations).

Even if we removed all custom styles and format, the problem is not solved.

Is there anyone who had the similar experience or know the way to recommend to solve theses kind of problem?

Thank you in advance.